# nuxt.config.js: load different config for development or production

Tags: config, nuxt.js

How can I load for production and development different settings.

I want something like this for example:

## nuxt.config.js

```
  sentry: {
    dsn: 'xxx',
    config: {
      disabled: !env.isDev
    }
  },
```

Unfortunately isDev is not usable at that stage.

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 different config files:

```
nuxt.config.dev.js
nuxt.config.js
```

and in package.json in scripts section specify config file for dev version

with `--config-file nuxt.config.dev.js`:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development HOST=111.111.111.111 PORT=3001 nodemon --watch api --exec \"nuxt --config-file nuxt.config.dev.js --spa\"",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production HOST=111.111.111.111 PORT=3002 nuxt start --spa "
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the good input.

In the meantime a found an other solution which is working fine for my current use case.

## nuxt.config.js

```
import stdEnv from 'std-env'

...
sentry: {
    dsn: 'xxx',
    config: {
      disabled: !stdEnv.dev
    }
  },
...
```

I think this is a good and easy solution if you have only little difference to your production setup.

At the end I will probably use a mix of both.

**EDIT:**
importing 'std-env' in nuxt.config.js gave me some problems on production.
I use this peace of code at the moment without any issues:

```
(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')
```

That way you don't need to import anything!